# Fazer o INSERT de uma Array, independente da quantia do $_POST

Tags: php, mysql

Por exemplo, uma pessoa adiciona muitas Imagens para serem publicadas.

Ela pode adicionar 4 imagens, assim como pode adicionar 10,15,1,3 e etc.

Como ficaria a **QUERY**?

Array do POST do formulário:

```
array (

[IMG1] => /img/nomedaimagemquefoiupload1.jpg

[IMG2] => /img/nomedaimagemquefoiupload2.jpg

[IMG3] => /img/nomedaimagemquefoiupload3.jpg

);

$ArrayDeUmPostComum = $_POST;
```

```
INSERT INTO TABELA VALUES ($ArrayDeUmPostComum)
```

Comment: Você está usando algum driver que permita usar PREPARE, ou seja, PDO ou mysqli?

Comment: Eu uso PDO, mas os meus códigos estão em outro PC que deu pal, vou ter que comprar um leitor de HD...Mas qualquer exemplo basta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se entendi direito, você quer inserir várias linhas na tabela. No MySQL você pode fazer assim:

```
INSERT INTO tabela
    (caminho)
VALUES
    ('...'),
    ('...'),
    ('...');
```

Para montar essa query no PHP, considerando o uso de PDO, e que no seu `$_POST` não vêm somente os caminhos das imagens:

```
$quantidade = count($_POST);
$parametros = array_fill(0, $quantidade, '(?)');
$valores = array_values($_POST);
$sql = 'INSERT INTO tabela (url) VALUES ' . implode(',', $parametros);
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->execute($valores);
```

Comment: Sim isto mesmo, mas como transformo a $Array em multiplos VALUES? DROPBOX por exemplo, você pode fazer um DRAG de arquivos que ele vai fazer o INSERT na sua database

Comment: Edite a pergunta e mostre como você recebe os dados no POST, e como é a estrutura da sua tabela. Está difícil de entender exatament o que você quer, achei que era a estrutura da query...

Comment: Veja se meu update ajuda.

Comment: Bom, não posso testar agora, mais aposto que isso irá me ajudar, é um pouco diferente do PDO que costumo usar, pois no $_POST ele é :nomedopost, :nomedopost2, e etc, Isso muda algo?

Comment: Não, a diferença é que com `?` você não precisa nomear os parâmetros. Esse meu código considera que você tem só uma lista de caminhos, então não precisa ficar nomeando um por um.

Comment: Hmmm, entendi, básicamente o que eu queria era isso, fazer o INSERT de uma Array independente da quantia do $_POST, muito obrigado @bfavaretto, assim que eu conseguir recuperar meus arquivos do HD irei atualizar meus arquivos!!!

Comment: Só uma outra dúvida aqui, isso vai criar diferentes datas na tabela né? Porque como no exemplo, a coluna url iria ficar http://minhaurl/img/img1.jpg,http://minhaurl/img/img2.jpg,http://minhaurl/img/img3.jpg,

Comment: Vai criar uma linha por caminho.

Comment: Assim?: http://notepad.cc/becsuwa82

Comment: É, assim mesmo .

Comment: Mas para incluir o publicacao id, use `array_fill(0, $quantidade, '(?, 1)');` (e inclua o nome da coluna na primeira metade da query)

Comment: Você vai precisar adaptar, talvez precise fazer um loop na mão pra montar a query.

Comment: oks, array_fill(0, $quantidade, '(?, $publicação_id, $usuário_ID)');

Comment: Use aspas duplas na string ali dentro, senão as variáveis não serão interpoladas.

Comment: ok;;;;;;;;;;;;;